# dpkg-deb: error: control directory has bad permissions

Tags: ubuntu, dpkg, deb, alien

I'm running an Ubuntu 12.04 VM and trying to convert an rpm file to a deb file.  When I run `sudo alien --to-deb --scripts oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm` I get this error

```
dpkg-deb: error: control directory has bad permissions 777 (must be
> >=0755 and <=0775)
```

I tried `sudo chmod 0755 oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm` and `sudo chmod -R 0755` on the directory containing the file and still get the error. What is the control directory?

**Update**
Sorry for not realizing this before I am getting this error before the control directory error.

```
dpkg-shlibdeps: warning: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXm.so.3 has an unexpected SONAME (libXm.so.4) 

dpkg-shlibdeps: error: no dependency information found for /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXm.so.3
```

I ran `sudo apt-file search libXm.so.3` and it returned `libmotif4: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXm.so.3` so I downloaded libmotif4 and still got the error and then downloaded libmotif3 as well and got the error.

I ran `sudo alien -g my.rpm` and that generated oracle-xe-11.2.0 and oracle-xe-11.2.0.orig directories.  I ran `sudo chmod -R 0755 oracle-xe-11.2.0` and then ran `debian/rules binary` to generate the errors described above.

Comment: you are better off compiling from source then converting with alien.

Comment: is the source contained within the rpm file?

Comment: no, it would be in the source rpm .

Comment: I highly suggest you run this on a .rpm system such as RHEL or Centos. You can try this - https://wiki.debian.org/DataBase/Oracle

Comment: Ok thank you, i came across that link before but it only has a .deb for oracle 10 and not 11. I tried on Fedora and faced a lot of issues with that and read that oracle isn't supported on Fedora https://community.oracle.com/thread/2279145?tstart=0.  I'll try Centos

Comment: The control directory is a temporary directory created by alien and eventually archived into the deb file. It shouldn't be created with permissions 777. Is your umask broken? What does `umask` show?

Comment: umask shows 0002

Answer (score 10):

If your control directory is on NTFS file system, you will get this error. In fact, your file system should support file permissions.

So the first advice is to copy your files somewhere in your home directory that has Ex4 or other file system.

Comment: this is not a solution

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on WSL (windows Subsystem for Linux)

In that case you have to create /etc/wsl.conf

With this content:

```
[automount]
 enabled = true
 root = /mnt/
 options = "metadata,umask=22,fmask=11"
 mountFsTab = false
```

I don't know the specifics of your VM.. but there might be a simlar solution.